# KML to shape QGIS conversion?

Tags: qgis, gdal, kml

I am trying to import a KML file to QGIS. The KML source file is about 15mb is comprised of polygons with attribute data. The KML imports fine and polygons display but the attribute data is unreadable - all contained within [Description] field but looks like this:

```
"<br><br><br>
<table border="1" padding="0">
<tr><td>ID_INT</td><td>NGA0104001</td></tr>
<tr><td>N_sd</td><td>Igbere</td></tr>
<tr><td>Skm2</td><td>3.34</td></tr>
<tr><td>PT2010</td><td>13000</td></tr>"
```

As I understand it the conversion is handled by GDAL. I'm running QGIS v.1.8 on Ubuntu 12.04, but have built GDAL library 1.10.1 against the libkml library. Even if I attempt to convert to shapefile using the command line ogr2ogr method I still get the description field parsed incorrectly.

I've tried various on-line tools (e.g.http://www.zonums.com/online/kml2shp.php) but my file is too large or description field comes out as above.

As anyone had any success with converting kml to shape and retaining attribute data. I've found the pykml (http://pythonhosted.org/pykml/index.html) library and have been experimenting with it using ipython notebook to see if I could write the kml to a csv file but equally no joy.

The KML is too large to post but here's what it looks like:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <Document>
    <name>AFNGA_SWAC.kml</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin1">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff00ffff</color>
            <width>3</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>3300ffff</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin1">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin1</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl1</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl1">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff00ffff</color>
            <width>3</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>3300ffff</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder>
        <name>AFNGA_SWAC</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <description>1027 Éléments de la couche Afnga_swac</description>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Aba</name>
            <description><![CDATA[<br><br><br>
    <table border="1" padding="0">
    <tr><td>ID_INT</td><td>NGA0101001</td></tr>
    <tr><td>N_sd</td><td>Aba</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Skm2</td><td>384.07</td></tr>
    <tr><td>PT2010</td><td>1010000</td></tr>]]></description>
            <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin1</styleUrl>
            <Polygon>
                <extrude>1</extrude>
                <tessellate>1</tessellate>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            7.294567000000001,5.00267,0 7.294408999999999,5.002552,0 7.294211,5.002394,0
```

Comment: maybe you could try using the command line version of ogr2ogr? this is the gdal tool for converting vector data into other vector formats. see http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's importing perfectly fine, and the 'description' field contains HTML.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Zachary: I humbly disagree. The answer is that it is working fine and as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Darren, I realise that its dumping HTML into the description field, but is this really what the GDAL driver is supposed to do? I had hoped that I would end up with the HTML/XML parsed to separate fields. Either way I need a solution to extract that information. Any pointers on that?

Comment: @marty_c; I think it is doing what it is designed to do, yes. In this case, the data in the description field just happens to be an HTML table. As for how to parse it out; that's a great question. Perhaps you could reword the question above (or start a new one?) to specifically ask it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817466/how-to-parse-a-kml-file-to-csv-using-python-beautifulsoup-or-similar

Comment: @DarrenCope; thanks Darren, I've posted a question over at [StackExhange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817466/how-to-parse-a-kml-file-to-csv-using-python-beautifulsoup-or-similar). I have a feeling that I could use the [BeautifulSoup Python library](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the html, but I am a little unsure where to start!